# Getting verification error when attempting to "adb sideload" the OTA update on Nexus 7 (2013)

Tags: nexus-7, ota-update, side-loading

Notes:

- Tablet is unlocked and rooted (SuperSU Pro v1.75)
- I have the following recovery flash in place: TWRP 2.6.3.0, but I am booting stock recovery for the `adb sideload` invocation
- The drivers are installed, host is Win 7 x64 and the device is detected in every mode (MTP, USB debug, bootloader)

When attempting to `adb sideload` (via stock recovery) the file `7d9b309e11da82edb5373a1f59965bca89f6041f.signed-razor-KRT16S-from-JSS15R.7d9b309e.zip` on my Nexus 7 (2013) [Wi-Fi], I receive an error:

```
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
Installing update...
Verifying current system...
"/system/app/Drive.apk" has unexpected contents.
E:Error in /tmp/update.zip
(Status 7)
Installation aborted.
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I have to change in order to make the `adb sideload` succeed?

Comment: There's also a chance you can use another recovery / bootloader. To install latest CM on my XT925, for instance, I had to use the custom image from download page (it's even a little smaller than clockwork's one). Also keep in mind that rebooting from fastload into bootloader can be very, very tricky, as it may be replaced by stock bootloader on reboot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Goal

If you have the OTA image downloaded and, as in my case, ended up without success you should be able to `adb sideload <filename>` it still manually ([video here](http://youtu.be/bgjH2E5oi0Y)).

### Problem/Error

... unfortunately the OTA update via `adb sideload` errors out with:

```
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
Installing update...
Verifying current system...
"/system/app/Drive.apk" has unexpected contents.
E:Error in /tmp/update.zip
(Status 7)
Installation aborted.
```

where `/system/app/Drive.apk` could be any system app.

### Who's *not* to blame?

- TWRP is not to blame, I thought so in the beginning, but it would work with TWRP as well.
- TitaniumBackup Pro. Since I rooted my device and use a power-user feature, I *should have* known of its side-effects. Now I do know, though :) ... and there's a good chance you learn about this from this answer now.

### Apparent cause of the error

Using Titanium Backup Pro I had used the "freeze" feature to get rid of some of the system apps, namely:

- ASUS Keyboard
- Calendar
- Calendar Storage
- com.android.providers.partnerbookmarks
- com.android.sharedstoragebackup
- com.google.android.voicesearch
- Exchange Services
- Gmail
- Google One Time Init
- Google Play Books
- Google Play Games
- Google Play Magazines
- Google Play Movies
- Google Play Music
- Google Search
- Google Text-to-speech Engine
- Hangouts
- iWnn IME
- iWnnIME Keyboard (White)
- One Time Init

This was apparently why the `adb sideload` bailed out early with the error message given in my question.

I also uninstalled some of the system apps, and I think I remember "Drive" (remember?: `/system/app/Drive.apk`) was one of them.

### The solution

I found the solution [over at forum.xda-developers.com in this answer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=47474021&postcount=26). The gist is that if you have a modified image, you need to restore that to make the OTA sideload succeed.

First download the stock image for the build you currently have. Make sure it's the correct one for your device. So I was trying to upgrade from `JSS15R` to `KRT16S` on the Wi-Fi version, which meant I needed to download the `4.3 (JSS15R)` image. That was the file `razor-jss15r-factory-ec2d4f76.tgz` in my case. I then unpacked that which gave me a subfolder named `razor-jss15r`. Inside of it there were shell scripts, a `.img` file and a `.zip` (`image-razor-jss15r.zip`). The latter needed to be unpacked. Then I had the `.img` files in the folder I unpacked the `.zip` into:

- `boot.img`
- `cache.img`
- `recovery.img`
- `system.img`
- `userdata.img`

Then I followed the steps outlined in the linked answer:

1. boot into bootloader (keep <kbd>Volume-down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> pressed directly after turning it on)
2. connect USB (make sure before that, that [all USB drivers are installed](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7))
3. change into the folder with the previously unpacked `.img` files
4. check from the Android SDK prompt that you see the device with `fastboot devices`.
5. then execute `fastboot flash system system.img` which will flash a stock system partition

**Note:** unlike in the linked post, I left out the step with the `fastboot erase system` because that is apparently implied by `fastboot flash system system.img` as can be seen from the output. I also left out `fastboot flash boot boot.img` and `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` because I thought it was unlikely that these "partitions" had been modified (I was right). You may need the latter two, though. It would probably depend on what you have modified that prevents the `adb sideload` step (i.e. read and understand the error message).

Here's the output:

```
# fastboot flash system system.img
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  1.160s]
sending 'system' (603447 KB)...
OKAY [ 19.786s]
writing 'system'...
OKAY [ 26.720s]
finished. total time: 47.668s
```

Et voila, a clean system that can be OTA updated.

So in short, you may only need to `fastboot flash system system.img` from the stock image you are running, if you ever get an error during the verification phase:

```
Verifying current system...
"/system/<SOME>.apk" has unexpected contents.
E:Error in /tmp/update.zip
(Status 7)
```

### Download for factory images (Nexus 7, both)

- [Factory Images "razor" for Nexus 7 [2013] (Wi-Fi)](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#razor)
- [Factory Images "razorg" for Nexus 7 [2013] (Mobile)](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#razorg)